# Using windows update agent apis remotely

Tags: c++, windows, windows-update

I am able to use the windows update agent apis for scanning the updates. I have seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),  saying that the apis can be used remotely. Please can someone help me to get started with using the apis for remote scanning.

Using c++.